# Jrebel error when setting it for Hybris with Eclipse

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

I am trying to setup Jrebel for Hybris 6.1 in my local. Using Eclipse, Jrebel eclipse setup is done and rebel.xml is generating successfully.

But when start hybris sever there are no logs related to Jrebel !!!

In jrebel.eclipse.log i could see the error related to DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider and serverId='null', server: 'null'.

Please let me know in Jrebel Configuration startup section in eclipse which option i need to select? Run Via IDE or Run Locally from commandline.

### exception logs looks like below :

2018-06-18 00:06:35.687 INFO  [rebel-ide-stats-sender-1] c.z.j.remoting.metrics.SyncTimer - No synchronizations since last stats, skipping sending sync time stats
2018-06-18 00:06:47.453 WARN  [rebel-messaging-executor-65] Metrics - IOException executing metrics task: Connect to api.segment.io:443 [api.segment.io/54.191.232.5, api.segment.io/54.186.237.16, api.segment.io/54.200.56.166, api.segment.io/54.187.120.229, api.segment.io/54.186.233.97, api.segment.io/52.88.28.138, api.segment.io/54.149.158.181, api.segment.io/54.148.149.96] failed: connect timed out
2018-06-18 00:07:26.467 WARN  [rebel-messaging-executor-65] Metrics - IOException executing metrics task: Connect to api.segment.io:443 [api.segment.io/54.191.232.5, api.segment.io/54.186.237.16, api.segment.io/54.200.56.166, api.segment.io/54.187.120.229, api.segment.io/54.186.233.97, api.segment.io/52.88.28.138, api.segment.io/54.149.158.181, api.segment.io/54.148.149.96] failed: connect timed out
2018-06-18 00:08:05.614 WARN  [rebel-messaging-executor-65] Metrics - IOException executing metrics task: Connect to api.segment.io:443 [api.segment.io/34.211.109.175, api.segment.io/52.38.249.149, api.segment.io/34.208.193.32, api.segment.io/52.36.138.212, api.segment.io/34.208.68.166, api.segment.io/35.161.150.240, api.segment.io/35.161.85.99, api.segment.io/34.211.197.151] failed: connect timed out
2018-06-18 00:08:05.615 WARN  [rebel-messaging-executor-65] Metrics - Metrics message dropped, retry count 2 exceeded.

---

2018-06-15 02:16:53.433 INFO  [Worker-327] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:16:53.434 INFO  [Worker-327] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:17:09.200 INFO  [Worker-332] o.z.eclipse.nature.JRebelProject - updateJRebelEnablement for 'P/aviallstorefront', enabled=true
2018-06-15 02:17:09.201 INFO  [Worker-332] o.z.e.nature.ProjectNatureUtil - Adding nature org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.jrebelNature to aviallstorefront
2018-06-15 02:17:13.310 INFO  [Worker-332] o.z.e.c.ui.projects.ProjectsGridRow - [OUT] JRebel enabled for project aviallstorefront. Redeploy project to apply configuration.
2018-06-15 02:17:13.319 INFO  [Worker-333] o.z.e.actions.RebelXmlGenerator - Using existing backed up rebel.xml
2018-06-15 02:17:13.445 INFO  [Worker-327] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:17:13.445 
2018-06-15 02:17:33.510 INFO  [Worker-327] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:17:33.510 INFO  [Worker-327] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:10.646 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:10.647 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:11.014 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:11.014 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:43.293 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:43.295 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:43.296 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:43.296 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:43.548 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:43.549 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:43.575 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:43.576 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:43.602 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType
2018-06-15 02:56:43.602 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'
2018-06-15 02:56:52.726 INFO  [main] o.z.e.l.l.DefaultRebelLaunchConfigProvider - unknown type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType

### 2018-06-15 02:56:52.727 INFO  [main] o.z.e.w.launching.ServerLaunchables - getServer() serverId='null', server: 'null'

and Jrebel startup section

[JRebel startup section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXyn.png),

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the below properties in your local.properties file ?

```
tomcat.javaoptions=-agentpath:"%JREBEL_HOME%/lib/libjrebel64.so"
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-agentpath:"%JREBEL_HOME%/lib/libjrebel64.so" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

Follow [this](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8be5ab06866910149c83e0bd4a187fd8.html) tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Free-Minded is spot on what is missing, but you can also check out the setup instructions from the JRebel side of documentation [here](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/hybris.html).